# CSS wrap text around image only if two lines or more

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      .container {width:300px;}
      h1 {margin-bottom:0;}
      .img {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        width:15%;
        height:100px;
        background:blue;
      }
      a {
        text-decoration:underline;
      }
      .by-line {
        background:yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <h1>Blah blah blah blah blah</h1>
      <div class="by-line">
        <span class="author">By: <a>Company ABC Incorporated</a></span>
        <a class="reviews">1232 Reviews</a>
        <a class="write-full-review">Write a full review</a>
      </div>
      <p><strong>54 People Recommend This Product</strong></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It currently looks like this:

[image]

What I really want is that if the `h1` gives one line of content, then the `.by-line` should remain to the right of `.img`.  If the `h1` content is two lines or more, then the `.by-line` should appear below the blue box at `left:0px` like this:

[image]

I can't seem to think of a set of CSS rules that will allow for this behaviour.  Can someone suggest something?

Comment: There is no CSS property that can be used here. Css cannot detect how many lines of text there are.

Comment: If you remove `h1 { margin-bottom: 0; }` it will solve the problem for the code you have in the question, at least.

Comment: But Paulie is correct; you'll need to redesign your markup entirely with this design requirement in mind, or use JS to control this.

Comment: I'm open to revising the HTML mark up.  But i prefer not to use JS

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was only a **flex** missing.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.head{
  text-align:top;
  font-size:2rem;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.by-line {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div class='head'>Blah blah blah blah blah</div>
    </div>
    <div class="by-line">
      <span class="author">By: <a>Company ABC Incorporated</a></span>
      <a class="reviews">1232 Reviews</a>
      <a class="write-full-review">Write a full review</a>
    </div>
    <p><strong>54 People Recommend This Product</strong></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Here you go.**

Comment: "*Actually it was only a flex missing.*" **and** an additional div wrapper. **and** applying styles to that additional div wrapper. **and** changing an `<h1>` to a `<div>`.